# "Отчасти" или "частично"?

Tags: выбор-слов

Здравствуйте. Можно ли написать "частично простить"? Не в количественном смысле (вроде "частично простить долг"), а, например, "частично простить автору его предрассудок"? Или лучше использовать слово "отчасти"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идёт о неполной (с оговорками и т. п.) "степени" прощения *единственного* предрассудка, то да - из двух вариантов подойдёт только "**отчасти**". Чтобы говорить о *частичности*, должны упоминаться сущности, очевидным образом делимые на части или разбираемые по штукам; при этом смысл будет заключаться в том, что напр. "прощение" (возможно, и полное) относится не ко всем упомянутым проступкам. Грубо говоря, "с него частично сняли судимости" означает, что их "сняли не все". Пример заголовка из "Коммерсанта" http://www.kommersant.ru/doc/2850012:

> *Адвокаты частично согласились с довод**ами** следствия и прокуратуры*

(= с одними доводами согласились, с другими - нет).

Answer (score 1):

*Отнестись снисходительно к предрассудкам.* Такое возможно. Ни *предрассудок* (в ед.ч.), ни *простить*, тем более *частично* принять трудно.

Comment: Чем плохо выражение "простить предрассудок"?

Comment: Предрассудки — помутнённое сознание, беда для человека и возврат его к язычеству. Пожалеть язычника можно. А простить? Что прощать-то? Он же не виноват, что не воспитан.